# How to convert dynamic nested json into csv?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have some dynamically generated nested json that I want to convert to a CSV file using python. I am trying to use pandas for this. My question is - is there a way to use this and flatten the json data to put in the csv without knowing the json keys that need flattened in advance? An example of my data is this:

```
{
"reports": [
    {
     "name": "report_1",
     "details": {
        "id": "123",
        "more info": "zyx",
        "people": [
            "person1",
            "person2"
            ]
         }
    },
    {
     "name": "report_2",
     "details": {
        "id": "123",
        "more info": "zyx",
        "actions": [
            "action1",
            "action2"
            ]
         }
    }
]
}
```

More nested json objects can be dynamically generated in the "details" section that I do not know about in advance but need to be represented in their own cell in the csv.

For the above example, I'd want the csv to look something like this:

```
Name,       Id,   More Info,   People_1,    People_2,   Actions_1,  Actions_2
report_1,   123,    zxy,       person1,      person2,            ,      
report_2,   123,    zxy ,             ,             ,    action1 ,  action2
```

Here's the code I have:

```
data = json.loads('{"reports": [{"name": "report_1","details": {"id": "123","more info": "zyx","people": ["person1","person2"]}},{"name": "report_2","details": {"id": "123","more info": "zyx","actions": ["action1","action2"]}}]}')
df = pd.json_normalize(data['reports'])
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

And here is the outcome currently:

```
,name,details.id,details.more info,details.people,details.actions
0,report_1,123,zyx,"['person1', 'person2']",
1,report_2,123,zyx,,"['action1', 'action2']"
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome for your example?

Comment: Edited my question with example csv

Answer (score 0):

I think what your are lookig for is:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: I've edited my post with code and results. Using normalise I still can't get nested field that I don't know the names of upfront to have their own column

Answer (score 0):

If using pandas doesn't work for you, here's the more canonical Python way of doing it.

You're trying to write out a CSV file, and that implicitly means you must write out a header containing all the keys.

The constraint that you don't know the keys in advance means you can't do this in a single pass.

```py
def convert_record_to_flat_dict(record):
    # You need to figure out exactly how you want to do this; everything
    # should be strings.
    record.update(record.pop('details'))
    return record

header = {}
rows = [[]]  # Leave the header row blank for now.
csv_out = csv.writer(buffer)

for record in report:
    record = convert_record_to_flat_dict(record)
    for key in record.keys():
        if key not in header:
            header[key] = len(header)
            rows[0].append(key)
    row = [''] * len(header)
    for key, index in header.items():
        row[index] = record.get(key, '')
    rows.append(row)

# And you can go back to ensure all rows have the same number of keys:
for row in rows:
    row.extend([''] * (len(row) - len(header)))
```

Now you have a list of lists that's ready to be sent to csv.csvwriter() or the like.

If memory is an issue, another technique is to write out a temporary file and then reprocess it once you know the header.